# Redux combineReducers() isn't recognising state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers, redux-reducers

I am using redux combineReducers() to combine 2 reducers. While they are both recognised in dev tools, one of them is simply an empty object, even though I passed an object with different properties into the reducer.

The combineReducers() file:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { default as JobReducer } from './Jobs/reducer'
import { default as AuthReducer } from './Auth/reducer'

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
    job: JobReducer,
    auth: AuthReducer,
})

export default RootReducer
```

The first reducer:

```
import { SINGLE_JOB_POST_SUCCESS } from './constants'

const initial = {
    jobs: [],
    job: {}
}

export default (state = initial, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action
    switch (type) {
        case SINGLE_JOB_POST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                jobs: [
                    ...state.jobs,
                    ...payload
                ]
            }
        default:
            return {}
    }
}
```

The second reducer:

```
import { RESET_AUTH_RESPONSE } from './constants'

const initial = {
    authResponse: null,
    user: {}
}

export default (state = initial, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action
    switch (type) {
        case RESET_AUTH_RESPONSE:
            return {
                ...state,
                authResponse: null
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

When I look at the state in redux dev tools, "auth" has the relevant properties, but "job" is simply an empty object. I have called the reducer files different names so as to remove the need for aliases but it had no effect. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `authReducer` has:

```js
        default:
            return {}
```

So, any time it sees an action it doesn't recognize, it'll return an empty object.  You need it to be `return state` instead.

Also, note that you should switch to using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which will simplify your Redux logic considerably.